# tKinter - How to merge with an existing application?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm sorry, I'm as new to programming as can be (I have a sys-admin background but I'm really interested in the development side of problem solving). If I ask illogical questions or I'm not posting how I should, please understand I'm trying to learn and I'm very open to corrections.

*TLTR: I'm very new and heavily modified a Python 2.7 code I found online years ago for a method to "lock" windows folders. I'm looking to update my app/program to utilize tKinter to replace the current command prompt password entry process in place but lack the programming knowledge for logically what I'm missing.*

How it works functional:

1. Run the .exe (I converted the .py file not knowing I could run easy by changing extension from py to .pyw, again very new)
2. Pop-up prompt requests password (not tKinter, just a command prompt box I customized the size, banner, and prompt for)
3. When correct password is entered, a folder that is hidden elsewhere on the PC becomes unhidden, the name changes, and it appears on the desktop. (If no folder was created in the first place, it will create one; not included in code below.)
4. After files are added, the same password can be entered which changes the desktop folder's attribute to be hidden and placed back to the hidden location

If password fails, the pop-up prompt states there's an incorrect password then loops back to the password entry. (Left this part out below as idk how much code I should be giving)

```
import base64  
import os  
import time  
import sys  
import getpass  
import shutil

#Set Password  
pw = "p@ssword"
encode = base64.b64encode(pw)

#Custom window size  
os.system("mode con: cols=40 lines=4")

def goto(linenum):
    global line
    line = linenum

line = 1
while True:
    #Customizable welcome banner  
    print "****************************************"
    print "               Welcome:"
    print "****************************************"

    pw = (getpass.getpass('Password: '))
    pass

    goto(1)

    #Hides password input  
    if pw == base64.b64decode(encode):
        # Sets the path where you want BitLocker to show up
        os.chdir("C:\Users\WINUSER\Desktop")
        #Checks for existing BitLocker folder  
        if not os.path.exists("BitLocker"):
            #If BitLocker folder isn't found, it checks for BitLocker.{CLSID}  
            if not os.path.exists("BitLocker.{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}"):
                #If BitLocker.{CLSID} isn't found on Desktop, it changes the folder name in hidden location to BitLocker, unhides it and moves it back to the desktop  
                os.rename("C:\\Users\\WINUSER\\Videos\\Captures\\BitLocker.{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}", "C:\\Users\\WINUSER\\Desktop\\BitLocker.{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}")
                os.popen('attrib -h BitLocker.{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}')
                os.rename("BitLocker.{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}","BitLocker")
```

I'm looking to add a tKinter GUI that works as a password entry than does the folder moves, etc. Would it be better to have 2 programs, 1 tKinter for a PW entry prompt that, when entered correct, calls to open another program to change the folder's attributes?

I've been seen code like what's below on here, but don't know how to incorporate it into what I currently have. I'm not too proud to be pointed towards documentation.

```
from tkinter import *

def show():
    p = password.get() #get password from entry
    print(p)


app = Tk()
password = StringVar() #Password variable
passEntry = Entry(app, textvariable=password, show='*')
submit = Button(app, text='Show Console',command=show)

passEntry.pack()
submit.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

**Thank you**

Comment: First of all it is recommanded to update python to 3.x, since it isnt supported anymore. To adress your question, the while loop becomes redundant in the mainloop and also it will interrupt the mainloop and cause the window to freeze. Put the code below `#Hides password input` in a function and execute it if the password validation is correct. As an [exampel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30828885/13629335). Note that tkinter is `import Tkinter` in python 2.7

Comment: I haven't upgraded to Python 3 because I'm truthfully not experienced enough to convert my code over and it usually bombs out. For how little time I have to really dive into programming, I'm working with this for now - I was able to integrate tKinter into my program today successfully with help from your example, thank you!